LINQ to SQL for Database indexing
//ProductController.cs
IQueryable<System_ExchangeRateEntity> qRate = _context.System_ExchangeRate.AsQueryable();

var latestCurrency = qRate.ToList()
.Where(r => r.updateDate.CompareTo(fromdate) >= 0 && r.updateDate.CompareTo(todate) < 0)
.GroupBy(r => new { r.fromCurrency, r.toCurrency })
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.rateID).FirstOrDefault());


var unitPrice = from l in latestCurrency
join i in qInvoices on l.toCurrency equals i.Inv_Currency into table2
from i in table2.ToList()
join ii in qInvoicesItem on i.Inv_ID equals ii.Inv_ID into table3
from ii in table3.ToList()
join m in qMember on i.Buyer_ID equals m.Member_ID into table1
from m in table1.ToList()
where i.Inv_Status != "Cancelled"
&& i.Inv_Type == "WS"
&& (i.Order_Date > dateCutoff)
&& (ii.Product_ID == filterProductID)
select new
{
ii.Product_ID,
ii.Order_Qty,
ii.UnitPrice,
l.rate,
m.Member_Country
};

//Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
{
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
});

However, I can just see the SQL for _context.System_ExchangeRate.AsQueryable() but the SQL for unitPrice is missing. I also tried LINQPAD but the change of code is massive. Any idea for outputing the SQL is appreciated.
I am trying to output SQL for the unitPrice. So that I can add index in the database clearly.

Give us some idea of what you're trying to do and which data library you're using and the class model that's involved. We have no idea where this query comes from or which SQL you were expecting. Does this code even compile? For sure, latestCurrency is not what you expect it to be.

latestCurrency will pass to unitPrice and groupTable for the data message.  I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; It connects to MySQL 8 database. The controller runs fine but is slow in return Ok(jsonData). I expect an SQL that is a Where clause so that I can add the indexing in the database. However, after trying a different approach, I only see the SQL for _context.System_ExchangeRate.AsQueryable(); Hard to get the SQL for unitPrice or the LINQ query for data message after unitPrice.

A few problem points I see. First the initial query:
var latestCurrency = qRate.ToList()
    .Where(r => r.updateDate.CompareTo(fromdate) >= 0 && r.updateDate.CompareTo(todate) < 0) ...

"qRate.ToList()" is a big no-no.. This is loading all rate records into memory instead of querying within the DB: EF can process date time comparisons. Adding ToList() is a common hack when programmers get an error that the expression could not be translated. It is a hack of last resort and not needed here:
var latestCurrency = qRate
    .Where(r => r.updateDate >= fromdate && r.updateDate < todate)
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.fromCurrency, r.toCurrency })
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.rateID).FirstOrDefault());

Next would be the lack of leveraging navigation properties. EF manages relations between entities to build SQL. It's not meant to be used as something you rewrite SQL in LINQ.
var unitPrice = from l in latestCurrency
join i in qInvoices on l.toCurrency equals i.Inv_Currency into table2
from i in table2.ToList()
join ii in qInvoicesItem on i.Inv_ID equals ii.Inv_ID into table3
from ii in table3.ToList()
join m in qMember on i.Buyer_ID equals m.Member_ID into table1
from m in table1.ToList()
where i.Inv_Status != "Cancelled"
&& i.Inv_Type == "WS"
&& (i.Order_Date > dateCutoff)
&& (ii.Product_ID == filterProductID)
select new
{
ii.Product_ID,
ii.Order_Qty,
ii.UnitPrice,
l.rate,
m.Member_Country
};

Here we should have relationships between invoices and invoice items, then invoices and members. (buyers) The FKs between the tables should see Invoice.InvoiceItems and Invoice.Buyer supported in the entities. I would suspect that we want all invoices but then marry them up to the currency information for the given date range. In this case we don't need to join on the currency details but can iterate over the results to fill in the rate and handle cases where a currency rate wasn't found:
var invoiceItems = dbContext.Invoices
   .Where(i => i.Inv_Status != "Cancelled"
        && i.Inv_Type == "WS"
        && i.Order_Date > dateCutoff
        && i.invoiceItems.Any(ii => ii.Product_ID == filterProductID))
   .SelectMany(i => i.InvoiceItems.Select(ii => new InvoiceItemDTO
   {
       ProductId = ii.Product_ID,
       OrderQuantity = ii.Order_Qty,
       UnitPrice = ii.UnitPrice,
       InvoiceCurrency = ii.Inv_Currency,
       Rate = null,
       MemberCountry = i.Member.Member_Country
   }).ToList(); // Consider paginating.

foreach(var item in invoiceItems)
{
    var currency = latestCurrency.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ToCurrency == item.InvoiceCurrency);
    if (currency != null)
        item.Rate = currency.Rate;
    else
    { // TODO: What should happen if we don't find a matching currency?
    }
}

This should be acceptable for performance if there are a handful of currencies in use and the # of orders being processed is reasonable. (<100k) If there is the possibility of large date ranges then the data should consider pagination where only a page of results is populated at a time.
Ideally in a historical system with invoices and currency the invoice would have stored a reference to the currency rate that applied on the date so we could just go Invoice.Currency to get the rate that was used for the invoice at the time rather than trying to look up rates separately. This would also speed up querying. The big issue with a lookup is that the data could be different between the time the invoice was first created and when it is later queried/reported meaning you could end up with different figures. Auditors/Accountants would not be happy. :)

Latest currency can be achived with the following query:
var qRate = _context.System_ExchangeRate.AsQueryable();

var latestCurrency = 
    from d in qRate.Select(r => new { r.fromCurrency, r.toCurrency }).Distinct()
    from r in qRate
        .Where(r => r.fromCurrency = d.fromCurrency && r.toCurrency == d.toCurrency)
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.rateID)
        .Take(1)
    select r;

Next of your query is a BIG question. You should not use ToList() inside LINQ to Entitites query - it is just not translatable. Also I do not understand why there is so many from without any correlation with the rest of the query.
Without changing your query should look like this:
var unitPrice = 
    from l in latestCurrency
    join i in qInvoices on l.toCurrency equals i.Inv_Currency into table2
    from i in table2
    join ii in qInvoicesItem on i.Inv_ID equals ii.Inv_ID into table3
    from ii in table3
    join m in qMember on i.Buyer_ID equals m.Member_ID into table1
    from m in table1
    where i.Inv_Status != "Cancelled"
        && i.Inv_Type == "WS"
        && (i.Order_Date > dateCutoff)
        && (ii.Product_ID == filterProductID)
    select new
    {
        ii.Product_ID,
        ii.Order_Qty,
        ii.UnitPrice,
        l.rate,
        m.Member_Country
    };

